# Is the code for transaction good and optimal in rails 3.1.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sqlite

We have following code in our out_logs controller for saving into two tables in rails 3.1.3 app. In order to make sure the two savings are done with completion or none, a transaction is used.

```
  @out_log.transaction do
    if @out_log.save && @part.save
      redirect_to part_path(@part), :notice => "Saved！"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Not saved！"
      render 'new'
    end   
  end
```

The code seems working. Our questions are:

1. Is the code above good practice for transaction?
2. There are redirect_to and render in transaction loop, will these redirect_to or render increase the execution time for transaction loop and therefore will lock the database (we use sqlite3) for too long?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: `redirect_to` or `render` don't act like a `return` statement. They just assign some headers in a response that is currently being prepared.

About transactions:

```
if @out_log.save && @part.save
```

The above code is sure to lead to inconsistent states in your DB: what if first `save` is successful and the second one isn't? It's even hard to imagine.

The solution is quite simple: use `save!` (with the exclamation at the end). This way if your validation fails your whole transaction will be rolled back (an exception will be raised by `save!` instead of returning `false` as the `save` does).